# Estilo de codificación

Tags: c

Este código me proporciona el resultado correcto. Sólo quiero saber si es posible mejorar la forma en que ha sido escrito en cuanto a estilo o si existe un algoritmo más eficiente para llegar al resultado. Está escrito en lenguaje C.

Calcular el número con 10 operaciones de ésta serie: 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /*En la serie el valor absoluto del denominador comienza en 1 y aumenta 2 unidades sucesivamente, 
    además el signo de cada valor se alterna entre positivo y negativo. Como numerador tenemos el valor
    4 en todos los casos*/
    
    int denValorAbsoluto= 1;        //valor absoluto del denominador    
    float denValorRelativo= 1;      //Valor relativo del denominador
    float valorSuma= 0;             //Este es el resultado final de la suma

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        valorSuma+= 4/denValorRelativo;
        denValorAbsoluto+= 2;
        if(denValorRelativo>0)
            denValorRelativo= -denValorAbsoluto;
        else
            denValorRelativo= denValorAbsoluto;
    }

    printf("El valor buscado es: %.4f", valorSuma);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yo diría `int signo = 1; .... signo = -signo; denValorAbsoluto = signo * denValorRelativo;` y me desharía de `if`.

Comment: Intenta que los nombres de las variables sean explicativos y estén completos, así será más fácil que otras personas lean tu código, y te será más sencillo volver a revisarlo. Por esto, te sugeriría refactorizar tu variable `denValorAbsoluto` como `denominadorValorAbsoluto` o `denominadorSinSigno`, o algo similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elimina cabeceras innecesarias**

Tu código no necesita `stdlib.h`, luego es un accesorio innecesario del que puedes prescindir.

Si en vez de un único archivo de una docena de líneas tuvieses un proyecto con varios miles de archivos, incluir cabeceras innecesarias podría traducirse en tiempos de compilación absurdamente grandes...

**Demasiadas variables**

No necesitas tener `denValorRelativo` y `denValorAbsoluto`. Puedes calcular en todo momento si necesitas hacer una suma o una resta atendiendo al valor de `i`

**Propuesta**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float denominador = 1;
    float resultado = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++, denominador += 2)
    {
        if( i%2 == 0 )
            resultado += 4/denominador;
        else
            resultado -= 4/denominador;
    }

    printf("El valor buscado es: %.4f", resultado);

    return 0;
}
```

Claro que, si lo prefieres, también puedes optar por no usar un `if-else` explícito:

```
int main()
{
    float denominador = 1;
    float resultado = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++, denominador += 2)
    {
        resultado += 4/denominador * ((i%2==0)? 1 : -1);
    }

    printf("El valor buscado es: %.4f", resultado);

    return 0;
}
```